# Calculate the partial pressure of NO2

Tags: equilibrium, pressure

Calculate the partial pressure of $\ce{NO2}$.

$$p_{\ce{N2}}/p_{\ce{O2}}=5$$

$$\ce{N2(g) + O2(g) <=> 2NO(g)}$$

Let’s assume $K=0.1$

$$K= \frac{p_{\ce{NO}}^2}{p_{\ce{O2}}\cdot p_{\ce{N2}}}$$

$$K= \frac{p_{\ce{NO}}^2}{p_{\ce{O2}}\cdot p_{\ce{O2}}\cdot5}$$

But how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.
Now you have 3 variables and 2 equations.
To solve the problem you need 3 equations.

Third equation you'll get from the partial pressure law:

> The total pressure of an ideal gas mixture is the sum of the partial pressures of each individual gas in the mixture.

Tip: suppose total pressure is 1.

Comment: so? p(o2)+p(N2) =1
Aha so I can choose whatever sum I want?

Comment: Don't forget about NO.

Answer (score 1):

When applying partial pressures please do not forget the partial pressure that the product itself exerts (NO)

So we have: p(O2)+ p(N2) + p(NO) = total pressure of the system.